# Checking The WHERE CLAUSE clause in rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a named scope in rails and i have model by name Product

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
 scope :old_products, -> { where("tagged_with = ?","old") }
end
```

Have any body encountered the process of checking the subject which is using where in the active record and that can check the what where clause does the named scope actually holds

In rspec spec/models/product_spec.rb

```
describe Product do
  describe "checking scope clauses" do
  subject { Product.old_products }
    its(:where_clauses)   { should eq([
      "tagged_with = 'old'"
    ]) }
  end
  end
end
```

By the way i use rspec-2.89 version with the rails-5 version so any chances that we can check and verify the where clauses

Comment: Unless you're developing code where the SQL generated must really be tested, you shouldn't test the RAW SQL Active Record generates for you. It'd be easy for you if you follow the _test behavior, not implementation_ strategy.

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't think checking returned SQL of a scope is sufficient. The way I would test `old_products` is:

```
describe Product do
  describe "scopes" do
    describe "old_products" do
      let!(:old_product) {Product.create(tagged_with: 'old')}
      let!(:not_old_product) {Product.create(tagged_with: 'sth_else')}
      subject { Product.old_products }

      it "returns the product(s) with tagged_with = old" do
        expect(subject).to eq([old_product])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you still want to check the return query, may want to try:

```
it "..." do
  expect(subject.to_sql).to eq("SELECT \"products\".* FROM \"products\" WHERE \"products\".\"tagged_with\" = 'old'")
end
```

Comment: Ya thats true but how do you do the above process

Comment: Yes do not test the generated sql, as you do not control that (and it is not your wish to check/test how the actual query is formatted). Check if the intention of the code matches the result. Of course this is a little slower (checking the generated query vs actually runnning the query and comparing found results), but also less brittle.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
# This is better, more readable syntax for scope declaration
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  scope :old_products, -> { where(tagged_with: 'old') }
end

# Something like this would work
describe Product do
  context 'scopes' do
    # Set up something that will always be excluded from the scopes
    let!(:product)     { create :product }
    let!(:scoped_list) { create :product, 3, tagged_with: tag }

    shared_examples_for 'returns scoped records' do
      # This should work with shoulda-matchers 
      # (https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers)
      # Could also not use subject and do something like:
      #   expect(
      #     described_class.send(scope_name.to_sym) 
      #   ).to contain_exactly(scoped_list)
      # and declare let(:scope_name) in your describe blocks
      it 'returns scoped products' do
        should contain_exactly(scoped_list)
      end
    end

    describe '.old_products' do
      subject(:old_products) { described_class.old_products }

      let(:tag) { 'old' }

      it_behaves_like 'returns scoped records'
    end

    describe '.other_scope' do
      subject(:other_scope) { described_class.other_scope }

      let(:tag) { 'other_tag' }

      it_behaves_like 'returns scoped records'
    end
  end
end
```

- There is no value in testing the actual SQL -- it's generated by Rails; what you want to test is that your scope is returning the correct objects
- I would use `context` instead of `describe` when declaring the scopes test block because you're not describing a class or instance method
- Use single quotes instead of double quotes unless you are doing string interpolation -- it's more performant
- If you're early in the project and each Product only has a single tag, I would also rename the `tagged_with` column to be `tag`

Answer (score 0):

```
describe Product do
  describe "checking scope clauses" do
  subject { Product.old_products }
    expect(subject.values[:where].instance_values['predicates'].to eq(["tagged_with = 'old'"])
  end
end
```